# writing a macro for syslog in C

Tags: c, macros, syslog

I'm trying to write a macro for syslogs and its formulated as below.

```
#define MYLOG_INFO(...)   syslog(LOG_INFO, ...)
```

and used like this in code.

```
MYLOG_INFO("use: %s received\n", argv[0]);
```

However, I see an error like this.

> error : expected expression before '...' token

I tried changing for ... to `__VA_ARGS__`

> warning : `__VA_ARGS__` can only appear in the expansion of a C99
>   variadic macro

can someone point me with some hints in what is going wrong? -- thanks in advance!

Comment: In your first definition, replace the second ellipsis `...` with `__VA_ARGS__` and leave the first ons as it is.

Comment: Read the warning message again... "`__VA_ARGS__` can only appear ***in the expansion*** of a C99 variadic macro"

Comment: thanks a lot. it works after replacing the second ... with __VA_ARGS_

Answer (score 0):

I modify it as following and it can be compiled without error.

```
#define MYLOG_INFO(args...)   syslog(LOG_INFO, ##args)
```

You may try it.